# Looking Alternate Better Way Code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one image top of that I have 'N' number of links. On each click on it should open one small popup window. Below code its working fine but I don't want redundant code and one more thing at time I should able to open only one popup. Help me  better way code adn

```
$('.info1').on('click',function()
{
$('.info1-desc').css('display','block');

}); 
$('.info2').on('click',function()
{
$('.info2-desc').css('display','block');

}); 
$('.info3').on('click',function()
{
$('.info3-desc').css('display','block');

});
```

Comment: You can use a for loop.

Comment: You might try CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what does your HTML look like?

Comment: event delegation could help a lot

Comment: Use a single event handler and DOM traversal to find related elements. If you add your HTML to the question I'm sure someone will be able to give you a more complete answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pmvqhd/

Answer (score 1):

you could wrap all your links in a container listening to children clicks or you can use multiple selectors:

```
$('.info1', '.info2', '.info3', '.info4').on('click',function() {
  //little concat to get wanted block
  var blockName = $(this).get('class');
  blockName = '.' + blockName + '-desc';
  //first we hide all blocks, then toggle does the checking if is hidden then show, if showed then hide
  $('.info1-desc', '.info2-desc', '.info3-desc', '.info4-desc').hide();
  $(blockName).toggle();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Class name coming undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two generic classes, for example `.info` and `.info-desc`, and have only one event listener.

In vanilla JS it would look like

```js
var info = document.querySelectorAll(".info");
var infoDesc = document.querySelectorAll(".info-desc");

info.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < infoDesc.length; i++) {
      infoDesc[index].style.display = "block";
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of going along with what others have already said but something like this sounds like what you want, without loops:

Set a generic class "info" for all images (or in my case divs) and then set the specific ID for the element you want distinguished.

```
<style> .info-desc{display:none;}</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var lastID = -1;//DEFAULT
    $(".info").click(function() {

      if($('.info-desc').css('display') == 'none' ){
        $('.info-desc').html("<p> Hello from: "+ this.id+"</p>");
        $('.info-desc').show(); 
      }else if(lastID == this.id){
        //alert(lastID);
        $('.info-desc').toggle(); //COULD ALSO USE .hide()
      }else{
        //YOU LIKELY DON'T NEED show(), BECAUSE ONCE HERE ELEMENT IS ALREADY SHOWN
        $('.info-desc').show();//BUT FOR COMPLETENESS...
        $('.info-desc').html("<p> Hello from: "+ this.id+"</p>");
       }
      lastID = this.id;
    });
});
</script>

<div class="info" id="1" style="border:solid; border-color:red;"> 
    <p>Info 1. Click Me</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="info" id="2" style="border:solid; border-color:red;"> 
    <p>Info 2. Click Me</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="info" id="3" style="border:solid; border-color:red;"> 
    <p>Info 3. Click Me</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="info-desc" style="border:solid; border-color:green;"> 
    <p>Alter information using JS based on info-box clicked.</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tefw7s3y/3/

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT @PAM:

https://jsfiddle.net/tefw7s3y/4/

Comment: I don't want change the structure now., because its legacy project. Suppose user click number 2,  already 1 or/and 3 opened it should get closed and 2 should open.

Comment: Hey PAM, that is relatively simple just makes the code slightly more complex. Check my update and the fiddle, now it works in the way you describe. I'm not sure what you mean about not changing the structure though.